# MVC over byt Image upload and read

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, upload

I have 5MB-10MB image file, first step I add this to my `web.config` file to allow upload:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" maxRequestLength="15360" />
```

This is the code in the controller to upload the image:

```
public ActionResult FotoEkle(HttpPostedFileBase UploadedImage)
{
    if (UploadedImage.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        int Number = (int)Session["UserID"];

        var FindeUser = db.TBLLOGIN.Where(m => m.UserID == Number)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(UploadedImage.FileName);
        string FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImage"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + FileName);

        UploadedImage.SaveAs(FilePath);

        FindeUser.Image = DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + FileName;

        db.SaveChanges();
                
        this.AddNotification("Upload done", NotificationType.SUCCESS);
    }
            
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

With this code, I can upload files, but I can't read it if the image is big - like 5-10 MB. Image looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXZO5.jpg)

I need help for :

1. With my code how can I resize the image?
2. How can I read images which are 5-10 MB in size?